# Why Chrome is always installed in C Drive/ Installation of Chrome for multiple users

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome, users

Why does Chrome always get installed in C drive. It never provides us with an option to change the installation path.

Also, if I do one installation of Chrome, does it ensure that all users of the PC have access to Chrome? I do not think so...can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post on a short blog on some main points on chromes installation procedures & preference for User Profile Directory. [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/01/google-chrome-installation-and-updates.html)

Also instructions to install chrome for all users. [here](https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=118663)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome installs wherever the machine's user profiles are (C:\Documents and Settings\Username\etc.). As I recall, this is a way around needing admin rights to install it.

Comment: Main reason why I use it at work. It does not require admin rights. This was a very intelligent decision made by Google!

Comment: except if you have a small SSD...